# Customization Default library

Tags: acumatica

Could anybody help me with acumatica? I have an application, witch connect to acumatica with acumatica libraries: Auth, Default_18.200.001, RESTClient from here: https://github.com/Acumatica/AcumaticaRESTAPIClientForCSharp I am using it like submodules - if somesings will change on git - I always can update it

I needed to add custom fields to the Project form. I did it - added fields, posted changes. After that, I created a new endpoint inheriting it from default endpoint - and the new fields became available to me when working with the Project entity. I achieved this by creating classes that inherit from api and the base model with overriding the GetEntityName() method.

If I need to change the fields, I will have to create new inheritance classes.

Perhaps there is some standard way to support customization fields? And I just didn't find it.

My Api extension:

```
public class ProjectExtApi : EntityAPI<ProjectExt>
    {
        public ProjectExtApi(Configuration configuration) : base(configuration)
        { }

        protected override string GetEntityName()
        {
            return "Project";    //base code: return typeof(EntityType).Name;
        }
    }
```

and model:

```
[DataContract]
public class ProjectExt : Project
{
    [DataMember(Name = "TestDate", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public DateTimeValue TestDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is related to custom fields inside Acumatica product. Custom fields should be added with DAC extensions (PXCacheExtension class), example:

```
public class MyContractExt : PXCacheExtension<Contract>
{
   #region UsrDateTime
   [PXDBDateAndTime]
   public virtual DateTime? UsrDateTime { get; set; }
   public abstract class usrDateTime : BqlDateTime.Field<usrDateTime> { }
   #endregion
}
```

Note that PMProject DAC in Acumatica is inheriting from Contract DAC and the field will be persisted in the Contract table.
If the field requires to be persisted in database (with PXDBxyz.. attribute instead of PXxyz..) it requires a database script.

It is recommended to add custom field with a customization. When creating a custom field in the Data Access section of a customization the wizard will automatically create the database script to add the column to the table.

External link, tutorial:
https://www.acu-connect.com/2019/02/27/customizing-acumatica-erp-adding-a-new-field-to-an-existing-screen/

Comment: Could you tell me where I can find the PXCacheExtension class? Is it in the AcumaticaRESTAPIClientForCSharp libraries? I saw new fields added to the Contract table. I made changes to aсumatica according to this manual that you added and also used the documentation https://www.acumatica.com/media/2020/09/AcumaticaERP_CustomizationGuide.pdf#page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=95,0,0&toolbar=1&navpanes = 0 on 265 page add new endpoints

Comment: Perhaps I am fundamentally wrong working with Acumatica. At the moment, the data that I need I can get using a request to 
*** / entity / Default / 18.200.001 / Project / ProjectID

I added an endpoint DefaultTEST and extended exactly the Project entity

and at the moment when requesting a new endpoint
*** / entity / DefaultTEST / 18.200.001 / Project / ProjectID 
I get custom fields with the Project model

Is this not the right approach or is it just another way?

I don't need extra data, the Contract model contains a lot of extra data - which I don't need

Comment: And also i can't find entity Contract in Acumatica.Default_18.200.001. And I can find only ContractUsage entity on swagger.json for Default  API endpoint, but it's different entities..

Comment: Contract DAC is on Acumatica server side. The REST client request the Project entity but the data is taken from Contract database table ultimately. The model classes you are referring to are part of a GitHub project that isn't part of Acumatica core product. To interact with the REST API doesn't require those models. The REST API returns JSON text data. You can read the JSON however you want. Using the model class from GIT hub is optional. Check this page for reference: https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=1c767ad9-da6d-4047-bc93-6970ad469504